# Move an updated virtual Server 2008 (VmWare Workstation 7) from c:\Old\VirtualMachines\Server2008 to d:\New\VirtualMachines\Server2008 on windows 7

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

How do you move an updated Server 2008 VmWare Workstation 7 from c:\VirtualMachines\Server2008 to d:\VirtualMachines\Server2008 on windows 7.

I moved all the files and created a new Virtual Machine. It boots but it is not up to date, with sp2 and IE 9. .NET 4 etc?

Comment: If its not updated then it sounds like you have Snapshots setup for the virtual machine.  You have copied ALL the files for the virtual machine plus the configuration file to the new location?

Comment: Yes all the files. You mean I have to delete all snapshot files?

Comment: Did I say you needed to delete them.  You just need to tell VMWare to load the Virtual Machine at that snapshot instead of the original state.  The solution of course is to get merge all the snapeshots together so there is only a single version of the virtual machine.  You have not copied all the required files to the new location.

Comment: Ok but to merge and consolidate you have to delete from the first place right? That means you cant move your snapshots?

Comment: You can indeed move snapshots I have done it before.  Just transfer the configuration file for the current virtual machine instead of creating a new one and attaching the vhd.

Comment: Aha thx gonna try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres what I did>>

1) I moved all the files to the new location.

2) And then just clicked the .vmx file. Was prompted that this was a move.

And all the snapshots were still there and updated Server 2008.